# how to select Datetimepicker control (Select Date And Select Time) on same control

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on C# .Net WinForms, inwhich i wanted to have a Datetime picker control with simultaneous selecting for date and time selection. I have searched through some sites, but could not find any solution. Thanks

Comment: see this [link](http://www.dotnetperls.com/datetimepicker)